# Create Database from Already Created Model from Previous Entity Database First approach

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, reverse-engineering

Is it possible to create database from the previous source code of .net core where the database models were created by scaffolding.

I have lost the database but I have my source code available is it possible to regenerate the tables in Microsoft SQL server 2016 from the models I have created.

Please let me know if its possible

Comment: Yes, but the result may not match your original database 100%

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just create a new [Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) if you want to manage the schema in EF or run [Database.EnsureCreated()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created#ensurecreated) to create the database from the EF model if you intend to manage the database in SQL Server. eg:

```
using var db = new Db();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

And in any case [backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) your databases.

Comment: in .net Core there is no such file as edmx , so how can I create the database from the models and context class which was created earlier when the database existed

Comment: Either with an initial migration or by running Database.EnsureCreated.